# In Java (Android) libgdx draw/ render animation when just touched

Tags: java, android, libgdx

In Java (Android) libgdx draw/render animation when just touched else it will display a specific frame from the animation. The problem is when I touch the screen it will just render the animation for a split of a second.

```
   //@render   Spritebatch sb;

   if(Gdx.input.justTouched()){
        sb.draw((Texture) animation.getKeyFrame(timePassed,true), Gdx.graphics.getWidth() * 0.03f, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() * 0.03f, (Gdx.graphics.getWidth() * 1 / 6), (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2) + (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() * 0.13f));
    }

    else{
        sb.draw(shot[1], Gdx.graphics.getWidth() * 0.03f, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() * 0.03f, (Gdx.graphics.getWidth() * 1 / 6), (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2) + (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() * 0.13f));
    }
```

Comment: need some more code of render method ?

Comment: I want the animation to  run (full animation of it) when i touched the screen and after the animation is completed, It will go back again to a specific position...

But this code that i post that is inside the render method does, was when i touched the screen it will just display he animation for a split of a second (like blinking).

Comment: @AbhishekAryan yes please :D

Comment: just a minute..wait

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second argument getKeyFrame(..) enable looping whether the animation is looping or not. Set it true. Why don't you use `animation.getKeyFrame(stateTime)` instead of `animation.getKeyFrame (float stateTime, boolean looping)`.  Make sure `Animation.PlayMode` is looped.

```
 if(!Gdx.input.justTouched()){
         sb.draw(shot[1], Gdx.graphics.getWidth() * 0.03f, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() * 0.03f, (Gdx.graphics.getWidth() * 1 / 6), (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2) + (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() * 0.13f));
 }
 else{
       sb.draw((Texture) animation.getKeyFrame(timePassed,true), Gdx.graphics.getWidth() * 0.03f, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() * 0.03f, (Gdx.graphics.getWidth() * 1 / 6), (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2) + (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() * 0.13f));
     }
```

Comment: Yes that's the correct form my bad, thank you... But when i touch the screen the animation go so fast. like a blink.

Comment: increase timePassed when you touched so that next time when you touched it start animation from that frame. otherwise if you want to start from initial frame make timePassed value to zero.

Comment: I'm sorry i'm new to this, but what is a stateTime and what does it do?

Comment: stateTime is the time spent in the state represented by that animation.

Comment: take a look of this https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Animation.java

Comment: My timePassed is this:
timePassed +=Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

Comment: increase timePassed when you touch your screen and on your touch up make it to zero so that next time animation start from initial frame.

Answer (score 0):

@AbhishekAryan thank you sir, i got the answer

```
 timePassed += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    if(Gdx.input.justTouched() || touch==true){
        touch=true;
        sb.draw((Texture) animation.getKeyFrame(timePassed,true), Gdx.graphics.getWidth() * 0.03f, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() * 0.03f, (Gdx.graphics.getWidth() * 1 / 6), (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2) + (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() * 0.13f));
            if(animation.getKeyFrameIndex(timePassed) == 18){
                touch=false;
                timePassed=0;
            }
    }
    else if(touch == false){
        sb.draw(shot[1], Gdx.graphics.getWidth() * 0.03f, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() * 0.03f, (Gdx.graphics.getWidth() * 1 / 6), (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2) + (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() * 0.13f));
       }
```